# show only one value from ajax return array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

How can I display only one thing from the array. Now it shows the whole array but I only want to show the reason from the array. because the rest is't really important. I have added index.php to show what I do there. I would like that it only showed the reason from data.

*test.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = "";
var begin = "";
var tijdsduur = "";
var aantal = "";


$('#datum').change(function() {
    date = $("#datum").val();
    console.log(date);
});
$('#beginTijd').change(function() {
    begin = ($(this).val());
    console.log(begin);
});
$('#Tijdsduur').change(function() {
    tijdsduur = ($(this).val());
    console.log(tijdsduur);
});
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
    aantal = ($(this).val());
    console.log(aantal);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            date: date,
            begin: begin,
            eind: tijdsduur,
            quantity: aantal
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#testajax').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

*index.php*

```
        <?php
    $date = "";
    $begin = "";
    $tijdsduur = "";
    $aantal = "";
    if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
      if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
            print_r($_POST);
            // echo "Yes, mail is set";
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $begin = $_POST['begin'];
            $tijdsduur = $_POST['eind'];
            $aantal = $_POST['quantity'];
            $eind = $begin + $tijdsduur;
            $startTijd = "$date " . $begin;
            $eindTijd = "$date " . $eind . ":00";
            // echo $date . "<br>";
            // echo "$startTijd". "<br>";
            // echo "$eindTijd". "<br>";
            // echo $aantal. "<br>";
            $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
                    $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
                    $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
                    $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
                    // echo "$cleancanmakereservation";
                    echo json_encode($reservationAvailable);
        }
        else {
            echo "No, mail is not set";
      }
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

console.log
[image: console.log]

Comment: `apple['begin']` this should work

Comment: Well first, thats not json for ajax to easily pull from. Its a block of mixed text and debug garbage from php. You will need to first return json and only json if you want to simply pull out `reason` from it. Otherwise you will be needing to parse all the 'text' returned, in js, to find what may look like a block of json. If you have control over the php the ajax is hitting... JUST return the reason, and nothing else ?

Comment: @IncredibleHat is right, you need pure JSON data in response to display it

Comment: I have controll over the php should I upload it ?

Comment: If you have control then do `data.reason` to access the message, but the returned dta should be valid JSON data. If possible paste the JSON returned data in your question

Comment: If I do `data.reason` it does not return anything.

Comment: There should not be any sting or extra char or string like in the IMG I can see "Yes, mail is set" before the JSON data. and that array

Comment: I added the php to the post maybe it helps because I don't really understand what u mean.

Comment: Just send the response of this echo statement only `echo json_encode($reservationAvailable);`

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataType: 'json' in ajax request like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "indextest.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            date: '',
            begin: '',
            eind: '',
            quantity: ''
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.date);
        }
    });

</script>
```

and in php

```
<?php 

$data = array('date' => '10-10-2010','date2' => '10-10-2010');

echo json_encode($data);

 ?>
```

Comment: it says empty string given at getElementById()

Comment: just try the above code in seperate file and see the console you get the output